# Is there a way to handle browser back events in an Outlook web-addin?

Tags: reactjs, outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am developing an Outlook web add-in using React and TypeScript. The add-in is a single-page application and has its own buttons for navigating back and forward. It is loaded as a taskpane in Outlook. The current behavior is that when a user clicks the browser back button while the taskpane is loaded it simply closes.

What I am trying to achieve is that the add-in listens to the back button click in the browser and handles it accordingly i.e. by navigating back within the taskpane rather than closing it.

I have tried listening to 'popstate' events within the React component:

```
 public componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('popstate', () => {
        console.log("Back button clicked.");
        this.props.onBackButtonClicked();
    });
}
```

The problem with this approach is that the 'popstate' event never fires as the taskpane add-in is hosted within an iframe. I have no control over the iframe itself as all Outlook web-addins are hosted within an iframe. I also cannot access the parent window of the iframe as it is on a different domain.

Is there a way for the Outlook web add-in to get notified about users clicking on the browser back button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the feature addin getting notified about users clicking on the browser back button, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Thanks. Does this also apply for Android back button presses or is there another way to detect Android back events for add-ins supporting mobile devices?

Comment: We use Android WebView for displaying add-ins and [popstate event is supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event#Browser_compatibility).